# Modificar ruta de archivo PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

He realizado un proyecto de convertir archivos de word a pdf, en la interfaz tengo 2 Textbox.Text (txtOrigen.Text y TxtDestino.Text), el conversor funciona pero siempre me guarda el .pdf en la carpeta original donde esta el archivo doc seleccionado, y yo quiero que el .pdf se guarde en la carpeta destino que el usuario eligió.

Llevo días intentando saber como modificar la ruta de guardado, pero no consigo dar con la solución y quizas sea mas fácil de lo que parece, como siempre muchas gracias

Dejo aquí el código

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConvertirDeArchivos
{
    public partial class WordtoPDF : Form
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog CarpetaSalida;
       
        string RutaOrigen;
        string NombreOrigen;
        string RutaDestino;
        public WordtoPDF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOrigen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog cajaDialogo = new OpenFileDialog();
            cajaDialogo.Filter = "Archivo Word (.docx)|*.docx";


            DialogResult Resultado = cajaDialogo.ShowDialog();

            if (Resultado == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                RutaOrigen = cajaDialogo.FileName;
                NombreOrigen = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RutaOrigen);
                RutaDestino = Path.GetDirectoryName(RutaOrigen);

                txtDestino.Text = RutaDestino;
                txtOrigen.Text = RutaOrigen.ToString();

            }
        }

        private void btnDestino_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarpetaSalida = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (CarpetaSalida.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtDestino.Text = CarpetaSalida.SelectedPath;
                RutaDestino = txtDestino.Text;
    
            }
        }

        private void btnConvertir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
           
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo(txtOrigen.Text); //Ruta de Origen del Documento
 
            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;

            object FileName = (object)wordFile.FullName; //El nombre del documento.

            Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc.Activate();

            object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF; //El formato en el que se guarda el documento.

            doc.SaveAs2(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            object savechanges = WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges;


            ((_Document)doc).Close(ref savechanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc = null;

            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word = null;

            

            MessageBox.Show("El archivo se ha convertido exitosamente a PDF");

            //Falta que se pueda guardar en el directorio Destino


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y donde se supone pasas la ruta de destino?

Comment: FullName probablemente englobe la ruta absoluta del archivo. Deberías revisarlo.